# Delay when navigating to activity using Navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Having Activity A using the following navigation graph:

[image: Navigation graph]

Where fragmentB to activityB has `popUpTo` = `fragmentA`. Whenever I initiate the navigation from fragmentB to activityB, there is a small delay where you can see fragmentA before activityB. I have tried setting long fade animations but that didn't help.

I found this same issue for `DialogFragment` destinations but currently concerned with activity destinations.

`main_nav_graph.xml`

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.test.navigationcomponenttesting.FragmentA"
        android:label="fragment_a"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentB" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.test.navigationcomponenttesting.FragmentB"
        android:label="fragment_b"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentB_to_activityB"
            app:destination="@id/activityB"
            app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentA" />
    </fragment>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/activityB"
        android:name="com.test.navigationcomponenttesting.ActivityB"
        android:label="activity_b"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_b" />
</navigation>
```

`FragmentB.onViewCreated`

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_fragmentB_to_activityB)
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to delay the "pop" of `fragmentB` until `activityB` has shown?
Let me know if you require any more code!

Comment: Did you find any solution related to this delay..i am also facing the same problem when transitioning from nested nav graph to root nav graph and it shows another fragment for very short time..i feel popUpTo method is adding that delay..